# windows 7, php 5.3, when fetching binary data with sqlsrv from mssql the data is doubled

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

ok, so I have images on a MSSQL 2005 (express) server which I want to write to files.
with the same piece of code, on linux it works fine, on windows it writes the data twice in the file

```
file_put_contents($file, $val);
$val = basename($file);
```

I know it is not a file_put_contents() problem because I also tried with fwrite
the output file in windows has double the size it has in linux

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dimitris dimitris  891768 2011-11-22 16:13 eshop_products__2201.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dimitris dimitris  445884 2011-11-21 19:15 eshop_products__2201_linux.jpg
```

I am using the freetds driver for linux and php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9 in windows

any ideas on something I could do to get the correct data in windows? maybe some configuration I missed?

topmost bytes of each file:

windows file:

```
ASCII (php substr):
FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB0043000302020302020303030304030304050805050404050A070706080C0...etc...

hex:
00000000:  46 46 44 38 46 46 45 30  30 30 31 30 34 41 34 36  FFD8FFE000104A46
00000010:  34 39 34 36 30 30 30 31  30 31 30 30 30 30 30 31  4946000101000001
00000020:  30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30  46 46 44 42 30 30 34 33  00010000FFDB0043
00000030:  30 30 30 33 30 32 30 32  30 33 30 32 30 32 30 33  0003020203020203
00000040:  30 33 30 33 30 33 30 34  30 33 30 33 30 34 30 35  0303030403030405
00000050:  30 38 30 35 30 35 30 34  30 34 30 35 30 41 30 37  0805050404050A07
00000060:  30 37 30 36 30 38 30 43  30 41 30 43 30 43 30 42  0706080C0A0C0C0B
```

linux file:

```
ASCII (php substr):
����JFIF��C

hex:
00000000:  ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46  49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01  ......JFIF......
00000010:  00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43  00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03  .......C........
00000020:  03 03 03 04 03 03 04 05  08 05 05 04 04 05 0a 07  ................
00000030:  07 06 08 0c 0a 0c 0c 0b  0a 0b 0b 0d 0e 12 10 0d  ................
00000040:  0e 11 0e 0b 0b 10 16 10  11 13 14 15 15 15 0c 0f  ................
00000050:  17 18 16 14 18 12 14 15  14 ff db 00 43 01 03 04  ............C...
00000060:  04 05 04 05 09 05 05 09  14 0d 0b 0d 14 14 14 14  ................
00000070:  14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14  14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14  ................
```

The code extracting the file from the database is base on the yii framework, using yii's commands feature (php cli)

Connection strings:

linux

```
'connectionString' => 'dblib:host=192.168.56.101;port=1433;dbname=mssqldb',
```

windows

```
'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=192.168.56.101;Database=mssqldb',
```

Code:

```
$rows = $this->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM $viewName WHERE 1=1")->queryAll();

/*
 * Convert charset and extract photos from view
 */
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // convert charset / export photos
    foreach ($row as $key => &$val) {
        // charset conversion, on fields that do not contain photos
        // $viewCfg is an array I maintain to know which field does what
        if (empty($viewCfg['photos']) || !in_array($key, $viewCfg['photos'])) {
            $val = @iconv("Windows-1253", "UTF-8", $val);
        // grab image in file
        } else {
            $id = '';
            foreach ($viewCfg['keys'] as $fieldName) {
                $id .= '_' . $row[$fieldName];
            }

            $file = Yii::app()->params['pathPhotos'] . '/' . $viewName . '_' . $id . '.jpg';

            if ($val) {
                if (file_exists($file) && (file_get_contents($file)!=$val))
                    unlink($file);

                file_put_contents($file, $val);
                $val = basename($file);
            }
        }
    }
// ... do the rest
```

Comment: this is not enough helpful information on your question. please insert more code (with query). When you echo the result of count($val) instead of writing the string to a file, is the result the same? (double the size on windows as opposed to linux) i guess "file_put_contents" is not the culprit here, so we really need to see your database handling code!

Comment: Please post the first few lines of each file (in hex & ascii preferably), maybe your windows part did not convert from Hex back to binary?

Comment: did provide some more information... any ideas are very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: actually, it was exactly what @StephanB suggested. my current solution is to `if (PHP_OS != 'Linux') { $val = pack('H*', $val); }` which of course is not satisfactory enough

Answer (score 1):

Good to hear you found *some* solution, if not a nice one : /

I had that situation while testing Mssql on a PHP app but never got any further. Another hint you may check is the PHP doc on PDO Large Objects (like varbinary and image SQL Datatypes): https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php

Maybe the result is consistent when you read the image as a stream?

Comment: Might work really, but at this time the other solution works and it's online on a past project which I rather not touch. Until I do I will leave the question unanswered so if anyone faces the same problem and doesn't want to bother looking at pdo large objects can read up and see the workaround solution

Comment: Doesn't work! The SQLSRV driver still converts everything to hex `$res = hex2bin($res);` works :/